# How to disable new password Autofill feature in iOS 11 applications in Hybrid Phonegap Apps?

Tags: ios, cordova, textfield, hybrid-mobile-app

I am making a Phonegap Hybrid App using cordova. App is working fine in iPhone and Android, But in iOS 11 in iPhone new password autofill feature is coming on every text field.

[image: screenshot of keyboard]

How can I disable this password autofill feature in every textfield?